# All tabs missing from Magento Admin Panel

Tags: admin-panel

After installing the extension: magento-community/Beecoder_Beeshopy, and following the instructions, I no longer have any tabs in the Admin Panel.  I have checked the permissions on the js folder, they were correct however I still renamed the js folder and reinstalled it, but that didn't fix the problem. Magento 1.7.0.2.  Any ideas?

Comment: Was Magento compiler enabled during install? Did you flush the entire cache (not only `var/cache/` but also `media/css/`, `media/css_secure/` and `media/js/` directories)? Are there any errors in your `var/report/` or `var/log/` folders? Did you delete your browser cache or try another browser to login to the admin panel? Try Google Chrome to login to the admin panel and use **Element Inspector** and see if any errors/warnings popup in the console. Please edit and clarify your question with more details.

Comment: My assistant says when Beeshopy wasn't working, he did a reinstall and believes compiler was enabled at that second install.  I did flush entire cache (all mentioned directories).  No recent errors in var/report/ nor var/log/.  No errors/warnings popup when using Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: Okay, absence of errors in `var/report/` and `var/log/` could be caused by the logging being disabled. So please check this in `System > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Log Settings`. If compiler was enabled during the second install, then try and delete the `includes/src/`directory (`/src/` part only!). The issue could also be caused by incomplete install.

Comment: Can't get to System > Configuration > Advanced ...  No tabs.  Instead of deleting, I renamed src directory to src back, and get HTTP 500 error on both site and admin panel, so I named it back to src.

Comment: I see, then open `includes/config.php` and comment out the two `define` function calls. Read more about manually disabling the compiler [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8538154/magento-died-after-compilation-how-to-disable-using-compiled-files-without-admi).

Comment: Weird, I commented out the lines and got the HTTP 500 error, so I changed them back to the way they were and everything works now.  THANK YOU, THANK YOU, THANK YOU!!!

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked out! I have added my answer, please accept it so this question will be marked as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was Magento compiler enabled during install? Disable it in `System > Tools > Compilation`

If you don't have full access to the Admin Panel, then try to disable the compiler manually. Read more about how to do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8538154/magento-died-after-compilation-how-to-disable-using-compiled-files-without-admi).

After disabling compilation delete the `includes/src/` directory (`/src/` part only!).

Also make sure to flush all cache manually and try to log back in.